# NGINX only executing "index.php" but not any other "*.php" files

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to setup a CMS to run it's installation. The installation files are a setup folder and a file called "setup.php". If I access my website at "example.com/setup.php" it tries to download the file, but if I rename "setup.php" to "index.php" and navigate to "example.com/index.php" or just "example.com" it executes the php file.

My nginx config for the site is this:

```
server {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ ^/index.php {
        # Write your FPM configuration here
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Whitelist
    ## Let TastyIgniter handle if static file does not exists
    location ~ ^/favicon\.ico { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/sitemap\.xml { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/robots\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/humans\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }

    ## Let nginx return 404 if static file does not exists
    location ~ ^/assets/media { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/storage/temp/public { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/app/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/app/.*/actions/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/app/.*/dashboardwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/app/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/app/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/extensions/.*/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/extensions/.*/.*/actions/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/extensions/.*/.*/dashboardwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/extensions/.*/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/extensions/.*/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/themes/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }

}


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I changed the web address in the config before posting for security reasons. I'm extremely confused as to why this isn't working as if index.php executes, all .php files should. Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and have had a long day.

```
location ~ ^/index.php {
```

should be

```
location ~ /.php {
```